# Which Great Elder One wants to be symbiotic with a world and rule it as part of its body?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, warlock, lore, forgotten-realms

My player wants to be a warlock of the Great Old One.  The campaign would be in the Forgotten Realms setting (D&D 5e).

He wants to make a pact with an entity that wants to gather all knowledge in the world and that wants to become one with the world itself (like, become a living world), to rule it.

That is a very strange concept, and I can't find any suitable creature in FR lore.

Maybe Zuggtmoy? I have no idea.

What creature, from the FR lore (any edition), would be most suitable for this situation?

Comment: Does it **need** to exist in FR Lore? Is there some "bigger picture" saying it can't be of your own design?

Comment: Definitely not Zuggtmoy; she's all about wanting to turn the entire world into a big mushroom farm, and not much else. I don't want to say more, though, as otherwise this turns into an "answer in comments"; I just wanted to warn you away from Zuggtmoy...

Comment: For what it's worth, Zuggtmoy is a Fiend, not a Great Old One.

Comment: @mivascott Yes, it need to. I dont like to make a homebrew for every nonstandard case. It would enlarge lore size when it is already big.

Comment: Not an answer, but I noticed that a creature that wants to consume (and/or possibly destroy) the universe could fit this description - knowledge is just another kind of consumable. I eat some food, the food then becomes part of my body. From one perspective that food has been destroyed, but from another it is now part of me. The GOOs are intended to be incomprehensible, this kind of misinterpretation of their communication would be well within the realm of likely outcomes.

Comment: Different mythos, but Grandfather Nurgle would be a nice option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While not defined as Great Old Ones, the following beings from the FR lore might be of interest for your goals (perhaps you could retcon these as aspects/avatars of the warlock's patron, or you could imagine that the warlock is misinterpreting the goals of these beings):

- [Araumycos](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Araumycos): A sentient enormous fungal growth that occupies a huge region in the Underdark. It wants to free all intelligent beings from the chaos of individuality and integrate them into the comfort of its collective consciousness.
- [Atropus](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Atropus): A undead primordial in the form of a small moon.

The Chained God [Tharizdun](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Tharizdun) could also be an option, as mentioned in the [answer by David Coffron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165790/44723). It is a mad god originating from Oerth who wants to destroy everything. Some cultists want to unleash Tharizdun onto Faerun.

Answer (score 22):

### On Great Old Ones

When it comes to Great Old Ones, they are meant to be enigmatic:

> Your patron is a mysterious entity whose nature is utterly foreign to the fabric of reality...

It is entirely possible that the pact your player's warlock is forged is to a being hither to unheard of, or at least not in any library or scholar's records. You could just invent a character to suit this role without affecting the lore of the Forgotten Realms significantly.

### You could use any existing entity

If you want to use an entity already in the lore, you could choose any number of entities, and just have the warlock be mistaken.

- Perhaps the Great Old One lied to the warlock about his intent (a symbiotic relationship may be more palatable then the total annihilation that Dendar actually desires).
- Perhaps the warlock is misinterpreting the cryptic nature of the Great Old One's fever dreams (**emphasis** mine):

> Its **motives are incomprehensible to mortals**, and its knowledge so immense and ancient that even the greatest libraries pale in comparison to the vast secrets it holds.

### Alternatively, you could use Tharizdun

Tharizdun is an existing Great Old One:

> Entities of [the Great Old One type] include ...Tharizdun, the Chained God
>
> [Player's Handbook](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#TheGreatOldOne)

...that could fit your player's desire for their character. In the 4e sourcebook *Demonomicon* it reads:

> The obyriths demanded that [Tharizdun] plant the seed of evil within the Astral Sea, promising him total dominion of that realm in exchange for his fealty.

While what actually happened in this exchange is a long story, if Tharizdun thought that some sort of symbiotic relationship with Toril would grant him more power (and if he could be freed from his imprisonment to do so), he certainly would accept that offer. After all, that is basically the relationship he had with The Abyss before the gods collectively defeated him.

Comment: There is treatment of Tharizdun in D&D PHB and DMG also, if you want to add that as well.  (And IMO a great choice/recommendation) ... and in PHB I seem to recall Tharizdun is mentioned as a GOO example ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Tharizdun is listed as a GOO, yes, but I don't think there's really a "treatment" of him in the 5e books.  It lists him as a god of madness but there's no detail given.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I'd need to go and check Mords and DMG which are not currently to hand.